# How does SSH Window Size affect in paramiko

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, paramiko, openssh

I am building an application where it SSHs to Cisco devices to collect output of `show` commands. I am using paramiko module in python to get this done.

While comparing the command output with that of `plink`, got to know that the output from paramiko is truncated. Tried with unbuffering and increased buffer size and it didn't help. Later, just tried with `window_size` parameter and it seems to work.

Below is my code:

```
import paramiko
sshclient = None
try:
    sshclient = paramiko.SSHClient()
    sshclient.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    sshclient.connect('mydevice', username='admin', password='admin12345')
    chan = sshclient.get_transport().open_session(window_size=500000)
    chan.settimeout(10800)
    chan.exec_command('show tech-support fcip')

    value = chan.recv(1024)
    while value:
        print(value)
        value = chan.recv(1024)

finally:
    if sshclient:
        sshclient.close()
```

As per paramiko document for [Transport](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.connect), `default_window_size=2097152`; 1597152 lesser than the default_value.

Also the partial log output with `default_window_size=2097152` is:

```
Authentication (password) successful!
[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
Secsh channel 0 opened.
[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
EOF in transport thread
```

Where as with `window_size=500000` is:

```
Authentication (password) successful!
[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
Secsh channel 0 opened.
[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
[chan 0] EOF received (0)
EOF in transport thread
```

Here it looks like, when the window_size is default value, the channel is being closed even before the termination signal from the server.

Experts, please advise me the consequences of reduced `window_size` in SSH and how will it affect my application?

Answer (score -1):

By modifying the window_size, you effect the maximum length a line can be before a return character is entered. If your application requires you to perform some parsing, and you want to call something like

```
value.split('\n')
```

You may find that the strings are being split more/less frequently than you predicted.