# Paramiko .exec_command stops working half way through script

Tags: python, paramiko, cisco

I am attempting to run some configuration commands on a Cisco switch using paramiko, However after running a few exec commands the command no longer works unless i once again log into the switch, why is this? Is there anything I can do to work around this as I need to complete all of the commands in one session and cant afford to log back in halfway through:

The error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 414, in exec_command
    chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 703, in open_session
    timeout=timeout)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 824, in open_channel
    raise e EOFError

It Seems to have an issue with opening the channel but im not sure

Comment: I had trouble pulling show command output from Cisco MDS Switches, using single connection. Guess this is an issue with Paramiko since opening a new connection too failed. If you are working on Windows, use plink.exe or on linux, use plink command. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318780/how-does-ssh-window-size-affect-in-paramiko

Comment: Thank you, It would appear to be an issue with the exec command I resolved the issue by invoking shell then running each command on a timeout.